# Oracle Database. Insert a copy of a row to the same table (Duplicate key error message)

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle database I have one table with primary key GAME_ID.
I have to insert a copy of a row where game_name = 'Texas holdem' but it tells me:

> An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.

This is query I am using:

```
INSERT INTO GAME (SELECT * FROM GAME WHERE NAME = 'Texas Holdem');
```

Comment: PRIMARY KEY means the column contains unique values. and now you insert a copy of same value, which means attempting duplicate. Attempt to use a SEQUENCE or similar thing in the PK Column by expanding you SELECT to include the column names as well,

Comment: How do you generate unique values for GAME_ID? Are you using a sequence? If yes, are you using it explicitly or through a trigger?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming your `game_id` is generated by a sequence, you can get a new as part of the select statement:

```
INSERT INTO GAME (game_id, name, col_3)
SELECT seq_game_id.nextval, name, col_3
FROM GAME 
WHERE NAME = 'Texas Holdem';
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me just offer a slightly more abstract point of perspective...

- In a relational database, table is a physical representation of the mathematical concept of relation.
- Relation is a **set** (of tuples, i.e. table rows/records).
- A set either contains given element or it doesn't, it cannot contain the same element multiple times (unlike multiset).
- Therefore, you can never have two identical rows in the table, and still call your database "relational".<sup>1</sup>

You can insert a *similar* row through, as other answers have demonstrated.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Although practical DBMS (including Oracle) will typically allow you to create a table without any key, making identical duplicates physically possible. However, consider it a big red flag if you ever find yourself doing that.*

Comment: Downvoted because it is not the answer to the question, should be a comment or a remark in a coded answer at best.

Comment: Upvoted: Besides it's not a direct answer to the question it tries to educate the OP in good practices on normalization to a question, without full context, smells like an XY Problem

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one row with the same key. Don't duplicate the key. Specify the list of columns you want to copy and leave the key out (assuming it is provided automatically).

Comment: I guess it's not, because when I don't specify the column GAME_ID it says "CANNOT INSERT NULL INTO GAME_ID"

Comment: Provide the ID the same way you provide it normally. You have to know how IDs are generated in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You try to insert a row already in your table.
So for example in your table you have

```
GAME_ID Name
1       Texas Holdem
```

You try to insert into your table this line, but the game_id 1 is already there
So if you want to insert this, you need to create a new line like this in order to generate a new game_id for this game name :

```
INSERT INTO GAME(Name) VALUES ('Texas Holdem')
```

Comment: the problem is that it's not generating automatically... I have set the number in the query like yours:

*INSERT INTO GAME (Game_id, Name) VALUES (250, 'Texas Holdem')*

Comment: @Mark2 try triggers, if you want to increment automatically.